# How to make SWT button Text BOLD

Tags: java, swt

I am creating a checkbox button with text in SWT.

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button button= new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);
button.setText(Messages.AnswerDialog_answer);
button.setSelection(true);
```

In messages.properties, I have the value

```
AnswerDialog_answer=Answer
```

How can i show the text(ie. Answer) of this button in BOLD?

Comment: You can try setting the Font to a bold font. How you do that depends on what sort of app this is. Is it just a plain SWT app, or is it part of an Eclipse plug-in where you can set the font with the RCP CSS support?

Comment: It is a dialog in eclipse menu.
Menu is created by using "`org.eclipse.ui.menus`" in plugin.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the currently assigned font for the button to be bold using something like:

```java
FontData [] data = button.getFont().getFontData();

for (FontData datum : data) {
   datum.setStyle(SWT.BOLD);
}

Font boldFont = new Font(button.getDisplay(), data);
button.setFont(boldFont);
```

Note: You must call `boldFont.dispose()` when you are done with the font (such as when the dialog closes).

I'm not sure that all platforms support changing the button font. The above code works on macOS.